# Postman Test - tv4.validateResult TypeError: Cannot read property '$ref' of undefined

Tags: json, testing, postman, schema, tv4

I am using postman, i have added a test to validate the schema of the response.
The schema and response schema return as expected, but somewhere in the following code i get the error "tv4.validateResult TypeError: Cannot read property '$ref' of undefined".

```
pm.test(tag + ".SCHEMA response matches required schema", function() {
    var result = tv4.validateResult(jsonRes, schema.response);
    if (!result.valid) {console.log(result);}
    pm.expect(result.valid).to.be.true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I switched to this little magic script

```
 pm.test(tag + ".SCHEMA response matches required schema", function() {
    var valid = tv4.validate(jsonRes, schema, false, true);
    pm.expect(valid).to.be.true;
});
```

and it worked. Not sure why, hoping for someone to add some clarification